# Remove element if anchor uses Javascript: void(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

```
<a class="slicknav_item" href="home">Home<span></span></a>
<a class="slicknav_item" href="about">About<span></span></a>
<a class="slicknav_item" href="javascript: void(0)">Services<span></span></a>

if ($('.slicknav_item').attr('href').indexOf('javascript: void(0)') > 0) {

$('.slicknav_item span').remove();

}
```

Using the above code, I'm trying to find anytime ".slicknav_item" contains "javascript: void(0)" as the href, and remove the element ".slicknav_item span" but ONLY from that specific "slicknav_item" element.

It doesn't seem to be giving me any results. I am worried the problem is the "javascript: void(0)"?

The problem for me is that the "javascript: void(0)" is the only thing that separates it from the other links. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute equals selector

```
$('.slicknav_item[href="javascript: void(0)"] span').remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w2axLrfb/)

Your code `$('.slicknav_item').attr('href')` returns the `href` of first element with class `slicknav_item` so in your example the `if` condition won't get executed. Again your statement `$('.slicknav_item span').remove();` will select all `span` elements which are descendants of `.slicknav_item`

Comment: and if space is different between `javascript:` and `void` in some instances could use a lesser specific attribute selector like `[href*="javascript"]` or `[href*="void"]`

Comment: @charlietfl yes... or starts with selector `$('.slicknav_item[href^="javascript:"] span')`

Comment: yup, definitely good to have an alternative, good probability of inconsistent spacing. `starts with` looks even better